# Python Formatting Float Decimal Digits with Separation (grouping) e.g., Underscore

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format, numbers

If it's possible to print float number like this in Python 3.8:

```
4321.000056 → 4_321.000_056
```

I know we have underscore separation (grouping) for integer part, e.g., `1_000_000`, but I searched around, really couldn't find how to achieve that for the decimal part in float.

There're some discussion ([link1](https://bugs.python.org/issue43624), [link2](https://discuss.python.org/t/add-underscore-as-a-thousandths-separator-for-string-formatting/7407)), but it seems it's just Python feature request, but if you know how to print float like that in the example, it'd be great if you can share with us.

Comment: How should `1.0001` look like? Like `1.000_1` or `1.0_001` ?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way of doing it, but you can create your own function to process floats in that way:

```py
def float_bars(val):
    if not isinstance(val, float):
        raise TypeError(f"Expected float, got {type(val)}")
    decimal, fraction = str(val).split('.')
    fraction = f"{int(fraction[::-1]):_}"[::-1]
    return f"{int(decimal):_}.{fraction}"
        
print(float_bars(4321.000056))
```

Output:

```py
4_321.000_056
```